# Javascript/Ajax login

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

im just getting started with programming so im still learning.
i'm trying to create a login system with ajax but there's a problem.
login.php file works, javascript however partially.

login.php script

```
    if($_POST)
{
if(isset($_POST["reg_username"])) 
{
$reg_username = $_POST['reg_username']; 
}
if(isset($_POST['newPassword']))
{
$newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
$hashPassword = md5($newPassword); // i know this isn't secure, will get into security later
}

try
{
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usertest WHERE      
reg_username=:reg_username");
$stmt->execute(array(":reg_username" => $reg_username));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if(($row['newPassword'] === $hashPassword) && ($count === 1))
{
    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $row['user_id'];
    $result = true;
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>$result));
}
else
{
    $result = false;
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>$result));
}

}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

javascript file

```
    $("#log_FORM").submit(function()
  {
  $.ajax
  ({
      url: 'http://localhost/login.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataTYPE:"json",
      data:{reg_username : $('#loginUsername').val(), 
            newPassword : $('#loginPassword').val(),
      },
      success : function(data)
      {
        var success = data['success'];
        if(data['success'] == 'true')
        {
          $("#mainPage").fadeOut(1500, "linear");
          setTimeout(appearEverything, 1500);
          alert(data);
        }

        else
        {
            alert(data);
        }
      }
  });

  return false;
  });
```

what i want to happen is if user logs in with the correct login information
stuff inside of -if- happens. otherwise alert happens. (this part will get improved)

the if part, i guess just doesn't get compared correctly or something.
i've tried removing if else, but then

```
 $("#mainPage").fadeOut(1500, "linear");
 setTimeout(appearEverything, 1500);
 alert(data);
```

gets executed even if the log in information is incorrect even though alert box shows that information was correct or incorrect.

i just dont know what...
i've seen this is how other people do this so i'm wondering why doesn't it work.

- edit
  did var_dump and it shows true in alert box
  here's a debug snip without var_dump
  oh and it executes else statement even though i inputed correct information and it shows that i did. :/
  [debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1idb.png)
- edit 2
  managed to fix it (luckily it only took approx. 20h :D )
  edited login.php -> removed code from else statement and left it blank
  edited javascript file -> changed to

  ```
      if(data != false)
      {
        $("#mainPage").fadeOut(1500, "linear");
        setTimeout(appearEverything, 1500);
      }

      else
      {
          alert(data);
      }
  ```

if i leave anything inside of else in login.php it logs in even with wrong data, and if the if statement in javascript file isn't data!=false same thing happens.

anybody knows why this happens?
i found a lot of posts concerning if statement in ajax not working, but nowhere this answer or explanation...

Comment: "// i know this isn't secure, will get into security later" we have a joke in the developer community about these things. It's called. "Oh f%#k another a%$hole leaked passwords."

Comment: Jokes aside. Check your variables with `var_dump()` and debug your code to find the problem.

Comment: managed to get it working. look at second edit.
and thank you PeeHaa. least now i know how to use chromes debug. :)